# .Net Socket enhancement to support ACKs and Chat?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, tcpclient

I have a server  which can deal with many multiple client requests.

The server uses a `Socket` and `TcpClient` -  for every client , it opens a new thread.

Each client sends data to the server and the server response.

But *HOW*  do I "send a data" :

- Client :  sends a byte which represents : "I want to send  data"
- Server : sends Ok I agree ( 1 byte of ack)
- Client:  Sends The number of the bytes - length of the data
- Server : sends Ok I can handle it
- Client : sends the whole data
- Server : sends Ok

I can also send files

It's all working great.

**Question**

Here comes the problem :

Those commands ( which I've written) are user actions.

Now I need to add a chat to this action screen

It is not a problem :

I will open a new thread which will always be in  "listen mode" for messages

But :

That thread which will always listen , will also intercept the Ack messages (which i've written above) from the server !

I dont want to open a new connection channel just for the chat.

EVen if I add a response type ( ACK or CHAT_MESSAGE) - it will be a problem because responses for the user action will end up in the listening chat thread.

How can I ( ideally)  solve this architecture problem ? Am I in the wrong direction ?

Comment: Given the language that you are using it sounds like you don't want to use `TCP/IP` but instead a higher level protocol written for the level of abstraction and reliability you need. Given the scope of the problem you gave, I would suggest using `HTTP/REST` as your high level protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to open a new connection for the chat you'll have to deal with a more complex wire protocol:

You'll have to message-frame data and chat message in a way that allows the server to find out which of the two is coming through right now. Depending on that data is being received it needs to be treated differently.

It doesn't make sense to read from the same TCP connection with more than one thread. TCP is not message based. The bytes that are incoming could be scattered arbitrarily across threads. A single thread needs to find out what type of data is coming and dispatch it.

Comment: +1 Just to make sure : when you say : _It doesn't make sense_ - you are regarding to the "listen chat second thread" right ?  not for the "server opens a new thread for each client" , can you please confirm ?

Comment: Ok but how can I _"message-frame data and chat message in a way that allows the server to find out which of the two is coming through right now"_ - Im sending you data ( you as a server)data. in the middle of the ACK process  , JOHN can send me a message.  what now ?

Comment: You could have the client prepend "chat:" for a chat message and "data:" for data. That way the server can find out.

Comment: The server side is not a problem . The server knows which message is what. as I said in the first bullet : each client tells the server : im going  to send X ( file /msg/...). The server knows each message's type. my problem is at the client side ! the responses from the server would mixed with chae messages and ACKS. USR i'll be happy if you can supply worded sample/phases cause to tell you the truth , Im pretty stuck on it

Comment: You can do the same with the server. Make the server prefix each message with what kind of response it is. If you need to match up requests and responses make the client send a numeric id for each request. The server can then return that id with the response. That way you can match them up.

Comment: Usr Ok I did something like this : the client sends only command tokens (byte actually ) to the server and attach  GUID to each token. I keep those Guids and Messages in a dictionary. then , in a different thread , the client listen to responses from server. then if a server reply with : "Ok , you can send me the message" - I go to the dictionary and extract the MSG via its GUID and sends the message to the server. But now I have another problem : what if in the middle of that sending file process -  the user send another command token: "send FILE" **before** it completed sending the message ?

Comment: How could it send two things at the same time? You can only have one thread write to the same socket at a time. You must serialize those messages in time. If the file transfer is too big you must chunk it.